# Find exact match between strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, function, exact-match

I am trying to create a function to get certain strings of a df column, only if there is an exact match with a string in a list. Here is an example:

```
my_list = ['Lys', 'Lysol', 'Cla', 'Clarins']

def test(row):
   for i in my_list:
      if i in row['Product']:
         return i
      else:
         return row['Product']

df['Exact_match'] = df.apply(test, axis=1)
```

Output:

| Product | Exact_match |
| --- | --- |
| Lysol Disinfectant | Lys |
| Napkins Lys | Lys |
| Cream Clarins | Cream Clarins |

However, I couldn't achieve my goal. This is the expected output I wanted to get:

| Product | Exact_match |
| --- | --- |
| Lysol Disinfectant | Lysol |
| Napkins Lys | Lys |
| Cream Clarins | Clarins |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, no matter how long your list is and how you sort things:

```
def find_str(row, list_):
    words = row.split(' ')
    for elem in words:
        for search_str in list_:
            if search_str in elem:
                return elem
    
    return row

df['Exact_match'] = df['Product'].apply(find_str, list_=my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-order the searches so that it's longest string first and also use `.str.extract` instead of an applied function, eg:

```
df['Product'].str.extract('(Clarins|Lysol|Lys|Cla)')
```